# All Mountain Bomber recommendations

Tags: mountain-bike, full-suspension

Looking for recommendations on a Full Suspension bike - trying to spend < $2000USD.

Looking for an All-Mountain bike - something with at least 6" of travel but I don't want a full on DH or freeride bike either.

I am really intrigued by the Specialized Pitch, so anything that approximates that configuration would work.

Comment: Perhaps include the location where you want to buy this, country/state etc.

Comment: Sorry, I live in the Pacific Northwest (Seattle) - I like "north shore" style freeriding (board tracks, log rides, teeters, big drops, etc).

Comment: I'm interested to see how you determine the correct/best answer to this. Our first bounty question, how exciting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pitch is a pretty good AM bike; I ride the enduro and I love it. It climbs ok, but can destroy really rocky, nasty trails. It also does really well on the FR terrain. While the enduro has evolved from when it was the same frame as the pitch, I think they would still be fairly comparable experiences.

You might also want to check out the [heckler](http://www.santacruzbicycles.com/heckler/#builder.php) (you can set that up to be just about $2k) or there's also the [Giant Reign](http://www.giant-bicycles.com/en-US/bikes/model/reign.0/3899/37071/) which is a great bike.

Comment: The Enduro is ridiculously sick - a little out of my price range though.  Looking at the Enduro got me interested in the Pitch.  

I'll have to check out the Heckler and Reign they both seem to be highly regarded on pinkbike.  I wish I wasn't saving to buy a house so I could just go nuts.

Comment: I talked with a guy over the weekend who just got a new pitch - he loves it.  I would probably stick with Specialized or Santa Cruz